# How do I write a ruby web crawler which uses chrome?

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a ruby web crawler that is currently coded to run in firefox.  How do I switch it over to Chrome instead?

```
def open_browser()
  tweaked_profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  tweaked_profile['nglayout.initialpaint.delay'] = 0
  tweaked_profile.assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer=false
  tweaked_profile['permissions.default.image'] = 2
  tweaked_profile['network.proxy.type'] = 1
  tweaked_profile['network.proxy.http'] = 'ec2proxy.csnzoo.com'
  tweaked_profile['network.proxy.http_port'] = 8080
  driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => tweaked_profile
  $browser = Watir::Browser.new(driver)
end
```

Should I just ditch watir and go with chromedriver or will watir work for this?

Comment: chromedriver is dead. watir-webdriver is the way to go.

Comment: chromedriver is alive, it's what lets webdriver drive a chrome browser...  I think maybe you meant chromewatir?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was thinking about chromewatir. :)

Answer (score 3):

Check out http://watirwebdriver.com/chrome/, which has this example:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
... 
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :profile => profile
```

Also, these SO questions provide alternatives for crawling sites: [Web crawler in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132595/web-crawler-in-ruby) and [What are some good Ruby-based web crawlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981379/what-are-some-good-ruby-based-web-crawlers)